# Asp.net session issue with new tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my web application their is a session by name Session["Dataset"]  which will be populated after some button clicks by the user, their are other sessions as well but this particular session is the most important session in this application. My problem is If the user opens another tab this Session [Dataset] will be available on that tab as well with all the data in it. How can I prevent this? I don't want to use cookie less session here. Can any suggest me any logic to solve this problem.

Note: on a particular button click user will be redirected to a page and on that particular page say Destination.aspx I am using this Session [Dataset]

Comment: Why are you using session? Session is problematic and prone to errors.
With session, you create global data which is not a good practice. Also, you may end up with RAM, even more so in this case where you are assigning a DataSet to the session.

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't be using Session to store so much info, as been told. But what you really need is to understand the scope of this data. If it is something that is not meant to be available all along the user's session, you may look for alternatives, like storing it at your database, associated with an identifier which could be passed to Destination.aspx, where you will be able to retrieve this info.